# I can't see my desktop only the terminal

Tags: login, login-screen

I'm completely new to this, I put in the cd and I get this terminal thing when I turn on my computer it asks for login and password I enter that, and then all it says is:

```
tommy@tommy:~$
```

Comment: What kind of CD are you talking about? Are you running Ubuntu from a Live CD? If not, how did you install Ubuntu? Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: Installed the server release perhaps and not a desktop?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. I do not understand the cause, but I found some remedy, maybe it will help you too:
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>
It opens virtual console where GUI runs.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> ..  <kbd>F6</kbd> open terminals as you saw,
and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>  .. <kbd>F12</kbd> open virtual consoles for first 6 users that logged in.